# Replacing Refrigerator Piping

Tags: plumbing, air-conditioning, refrigerator

I'm looking to do a little DIY project where I replace the refrigeration lines of my mini-fridge with some clear PVC piping to show what's going on inside. I haven't verified the PVC will withstand the operating temperatures, and I may have to look to another clear material, but is this something I can do without damaging the unit?

I believe the refrigerant will be highly pressurized, so I may have to replace it altogether I assume.

Comment: it is illegal in some places to release the refrigerant into the atmosphere ... also it is environmentally irresponsible to do so

Comment: what do you think you would see anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Take an on-line class, read a refrigeration book, take a vo-tech class, but do not try to use plastic lines for the refrigeration cycle. You will be playing with a loaded gun.

Answer (score 0):

PVC is a poor choice for pressure containment. It is common for air compressor distribution lines to explode after sufficient cycling, although I am speaking of only one personally known circumstance. Exploding PVC is frightening to see, especially in light of the fragments slicing through the air.

If you're considering to view the internal workings, you may be able to replace short segments of the circuit with sufficiently thick acrylic plastic cylinders. It is important to ensure that the connections used between the metal and the plastic are reinforced to prevent blow-out.

It's also important to consider that the "activity" within the lines is going to be fluid movement or gas movement and as such, provide little value.

You will want to know the substance used within the mini-fridge. A quick check [shows that R134a operates between 22 and 57 psig](https://sciencing.com/normal-running-pressures-r134a-8003413.html). [Another resource](http://www.tecumseh.com/~/media/north-america/files/guidelines-and-manuals/refrigerant-documentation_north-america/tecumseh-guidelines-for-utilization-of-r134a.pdf) (pdf) shows that condensing pressure for R134a is 97 psig, nearly twice as high as operating pressure. These figures are lower than I would have expected, but still sufficient to exercise extreme caution.

The same resource (pdf) shows that R22 has a condensing pressure of 158.2, surprisingly low in my opinion, but still high enough to be dangerous. Caution is indicated.

If you crack open this closed-by-design system, you will need to have the skills referenced by d.george in his answer to return the machine to operating condition. If you have a friend who works in the industry, he may be willing to assist you in this project.